# config.php Wildcard subdomain automation

Tags: php

I'm trying to use a wildcard subdomain with my application.
But it's not working properly...

Can you help me out, please?

```
$WildcardDomain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$WildcardTMP = explode('.', $WildcardDomain);
$WildcardSubdomain = current($WildcardTMP);

$db_host        = 'localhost';
$db_user        = 'localuser';
$db_password    = 'localpass';
$db_name        = 'localdb';
define('APP_URL', "http://" + $WildcardSubdomain);
```

The URL Generated is http://localhost/0/login/
The '0' should not be there...

Comment: Perhaps you want to concatenate (`.`) rather than add (`+`). However that can't be your actual code anyway, I think you over-redacted it.

Comment: I didn't realize but that really solve my issue.

Comment: Thank you @ÁlvaroGonzález !